# get avg value from mongo collection based on condition using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have collection like this

```
         lat        long       band_1
        20.4335456 72.2345456   34
        21.54355   72.21256    42
```

and so on

i want query like this

```
  select avg(band_1) from demo where lat <=19.4533 and lat >=21.454 and long <=69.5454 and long >=71.2443
```

i dont how to query like this in mongoDB

what i have tried

```
db.demo.aggregate([
{ "$group": { 
    "longitude" : {"$gte":73.83152067661285,"$lte":73.83841931819916},
    "latitude"  :{"$gte":20.19826172705546,"$lte":20.201649925580337}
    }, 
    {
        "band_4" : { "$avg" : "$band_4"}
    }
}
```

Comment: This will get you started http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/ & https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: @Veeram i have tired ur link come with this kind of db.demo.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "longitude" : {"$gte":73.83152067661285,"$lte":73.83841931819916},
        "latitude"  :{"$gte":20.19826172705546,"$lte":20.201649925580337}
        }, 
        {
            "band_4" : { "$avg" : "$band_4"}
        }
    }            but m still not able to get avg value

Comment: Move the query part to [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage and [group by null](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null) to get average value in matching documents. Something like `db.demo.aggregate([{$match:{ "longitude" : {"$gte":73.83152067661285,"$lte":73.83841931819916}, "latitude" :{"$gte":20.19826172705546,"$lte":20.201649925580337} }},{ "$group":  {"_id":null,  "band_4" : { "$avg" : "$band_4"} } }])`

Comment: @Veeram does this will apply "and" operation

Comment: Yes all query criteria in a document are implicitly [and'ed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Comment: @Veeram its works thank you bro..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {
        $and : [
            {"lat" : {$gt : 19}}, 
            {"lat" : {$lt : 22}}, 
            {"long" : {$gt : 70}}, 
            {"long" : {$lt : 90}}
        ]
    }},
    {$group : {
        _id : null, 
        averageband : {$avg : "$band_1"}
    }}
])
```